# Facebook graph api--get ids and names of all users who liked a public page

Tags: python, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get ids and names of all users who liked the public page called LeEcoGlobal. I tried on developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer by adding different field names and seemed like I can not get access to those information. Just wonder is there any way I can do that or Facebook just do not allow us to do things like that? 
BTW, I can get all the user by searching "people who like LeEco" on Facebook, just do not know how to get all those data.
Thanks!

Comment: no, there is no way to do that. why would you need the ids anyway? what for? you would not even be allowed to store the data without approval of every single user. they just liked your page, that does not mean you can do anything with their data ;)